# Error in binary read

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having problems with my solution, I'm getting this error message:

> `HttpRequest` does not contain a definition for `BinaryRead` and no extension method `BinaryRead` accepting a first argument of type `HttpRequest` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

The issue is that I'm using ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6 beta 5)

I'm trying to implement this:

```
byte[] Param = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Param);
```

Comment: Where is this code? In the Controller or View?

Comment: In controller, the Request is recognized i'm using the right reference.

Comment: Hi, did you solve it?