# Request BinaryRead in ASP.NET 5 (MVC6)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I had this code working in ASP.NET MVC 5, but I can't make it works in ASP.NET MVC 6 (ASP.NET 5)

Can someone help me?

```
public EmptyResult PayPalPaymentNotification(PayPalCheckoutInfo payPalCheckoutInfo)         
    { 
      PayPalListenerModel model = new PayPalListenerModel();             
      model._PayPalCheckoutInfo = payPalCheckoutInfo;               
      byte[] parameters = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);

      if (parameters != null)             
      {                 
        model.GetStatus(parameters);             
      }

      return new EmptyResult();           
    }
```

The error is in:

```
byte[] parameters = Request.BinaryRead(Request.ContentLength);
```

> HttpRequest does not contain a definition for BinaryRead and no
>   extension method BinaryRead accepting a first argument of type
>   HttpRequest could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?).

I have tested somethings like this, but not working:

```
HttpContext.Request.BinaryRead
```

Thanks.

Edit: Similar quesiton -> [Error in binary read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056402/error-in-binary-read)

Comment: And.. what is the error?

Comment: In Request there should be a Body stream which you should be able to read into a byte[]. Could you give that approach a shot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HttpRequestFeature object now provides a [body which is a stream](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/Features/HttpRequestFeature.cs#L31). So this should work.

```
    public static byte[] ReadRequestBody(Stream input)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            input.CopyTo(ms);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

and then ...

```
 var paramArray = ReadRequestBody(Request.Body);
```